# Find PointSize to fit UILabel

Tags: ios, fonts, nsstring, uilabel

Given `UILabel` width, and a string. What is the best way to get the pointSize that would fit just right into the label?

Example: I have a label width of 300 px and the string is `@"Hello, my name is byte"`. I want to find out what would be the biggest font `pointSize` without truncating it in that 300 px.

Some way I am exploring:

1.) Create a dummy `UILabel` and set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`. Then just get the pointSize from it. This seems horribly inefficient.

2.) Loop fontSize test with different value until the size return is equivalent to 1-line. Still seems overkill.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried just calling sizeToFit?

UIlabel *label = .....

[label sizeToFit];

Hope that helps!

from documentation

> sizeToFit
>   Resizes and moves the receiver view so it just encloses its subviews.

- (void)sizeToFit
  Discussion
  Call this method when you want to resize the current view so that it uses the most appropriate amount of space. Specific UIKit views resize themselves according to their own internal needs. In some cases, if a view does not have a superview, it may size itself to the screen bounds. Thus, if you want a given view to size itself to its parent view, you should add it to the parent view before calling this method.

You should not override this method. If you want to change the default sizing information for your view, override the sizeThatFits: instead. That method performs any needed calculations and returns them to this method, which then makes the change.

Comment: Thanks for the respond, but you have missed the point by quite a bit. I did not asked how to resize my label. My label has a fixed size and I want to know what is the best font size for it, so other labels in the vicinity can share the same font size.